# How to increase separation between several nodes in D3.js and color them?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, d3.js, visualization

I am working on a Chrome Extension that crawls websites and finds certain types of links and then once the list of links has been populated after a predetermined number of hops, the search results are displayed using a D3 visualization (I am using the Forced Layout).

Problem: In about a couple of hops, I have too many links/nodes (more than 500 on most occasions) and so the graph looks intimidating and impossible to read, since all the nodes get cluttered in the limited space.

- How can I increase the inter-node distance and make the graph more readable.
- How do I give different colors to my nodes depending on their category/class?

Here are a fewof snapshots of the search results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As is evident from the snapshots, things get pretty ugly. The code for my visualization script is given below, to give an idea of how I am implementing the graph. (I am very, very new to D3)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#tab_5_contents').addEventListener('click', drawVisual);
    //drawVisual();
});

function drawVisual(){
    var w = 960, h = 500;
    //var w = 1024, h = 768;

    var labelDistance = 0;

    var vis = d3.select("#tab_5_contents").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

            var nodes = [];
            var labelAnchors = [];
            var labelAnchorLinks = [];
            var links = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < QueuedORG.length; i++) 
            {
                var nodeExists = 0;

                //check to see if a node for the current url has already been created. If yes, do not create a new node
                for(var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++)  
                {
                    if(QueuedORG[i].url == nodes[j].label)
                        nodeExists = 1;

                }

                if (nodeExists == 0)
                {
                    var node = {
                        label : QueuedORG[i].url
                    };
                    nodes.push(node);
                    labelAnchors.push({
                        node : node
                    });
                    labelAnchors.push({
                        node : node
                    });
                }
            };

            for(var i=0;i<nodes.length; i++)
            {
                console.log("node i:"+i+nodes[i]+"\n");
                console.log("labelAnchor i:"+i+labelAnchors[i]+"\n");
            }

            //To create links for connecting nodes
            for(var i = 0; i < QueuedORG.length; i++) 
            {
                var srcIndx = 0, tgtIndx = 0;
                for(var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++)
                {
                    if( QueuedORG[i].url == nodes[j].label ) //to find the node number for the current url
                    {
                        srcIndx = j;
                    }

                    if( QueuedORG[i].parentURL == nodes[j].label ) //to find the node number for the parent url
                    {
                        tgtIndx = j;
                    }
                }
                //console.log("src:"+srcIndx+" tgt:"+tgtIndx);

                //connecting the current url's node to the parent url's node
                links.push({
                    source : srcIndx,
                    target : tgtIndx,
                    weight : 1,
                });

                labelAnchorLinks.push({
                    source : i * 2,
                    target : i * 2 + 1,
                    weight : 1
                });
            };

            var force = d3.layout.force().size([w, h]).nodes(nodes).links(links).gravity(1).linkDistance(50).charge(-3000).linkStrength(function(x) {
                return x.weight * 10
            });


            force.start();

            var force2 = d3.layout.force().nodes(labelAnchors).links(labelAnchorLinks).gravity(0).linkDistance(0).linkStrength(8).charge(-100).size([w, h]);
            force2.start();

            var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(links).enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "link").style("stroke", "#CCC");

            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(force.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "node");
            node.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 5).style("fill", "#555").style("stroke", "#FFF").style("stroke-width", 3);
            node.call(force.drag);


            var anchorLink = vis.selectAll("line.anchorLink").data(labelAnchorLinks)//.enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "anchorLink").style("stroke", "#999");

            var anchorNode = vis.selectAll("g.anchorNode").data(force2.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "anchorNode");
            anchorNode.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 0).style("fill", "#FFF");
                anchorNode.append("svg:text").text(function(d, i) {
                return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.label
            }).style("fill", "#555").style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12);

            var updateLink = function() {
                this.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            }

            var updateNode = function() {
                this.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

            }


            force.on("tick", function() {

                force2.start();

                node.call(updateNode);

                anchorNode.each(function(d, i) {
                    if(i % 2 == 0) {
                        d.x = d.node.x;
                        d.y = d.node.y;
                    } else {
                        var b = this.childNodes[1].getBBox();

                        var diffX = d.x - d.node.x;
                        var diffY = d.y - d.node.y;

                        var dist = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

                        var shiftX = b.width * (diffX - dist) / (dist * 2);
                        shiftX = Math.max(-b.width, Math.min(0, shiftX));
                        var shiftY = 5;
                        this.childNodes[1].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + shiftX + "," + shiftY + ")");
                    }
                });


                anchorNode.call(updateNode);

        link.call(updateLink);
        anchorLink.call(updateLink);

    });
}
```

The array QueuedORG in the above code acts as my dataset for all links that are being shown in the graph. Each entry in the array looks like this:

```
QueuedORG.push({url: currentURL, level: 1, parentURL: sourceURL, visited: 0});
```

Can someone please guide me to be able to increase the node repulsion and color code them? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the distance between nodes by using the [`linkDistance()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkDistance) of the force layout. This can be a function to allow you to set different distances for different links. Note that these distances are only suggestions to the force layout, so you won't get exactly what you ask for.

You could set this in a similar way to how you're setting the `linkStrength` at the moment:

```
force.linkDistance(function(d) {
  return d.weight * 10;
});
```

It looks like you're already coloring the circles (`node.append("svg:circle").style("fill", "#555")`), which should work. Alternatively, you can assign CSS classes to them and then use that for the color.

```
circle.class1 {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
}

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      if(d.something == 1) { return "class1"; }
      // etc
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I will get started with your suggestions and see if I can make it work :)

Comment: You have a `.force` in there that should be removed.